# ServerView RAID Manager website can not be loaded

Tags: serverview

I installed ServerView RAID Manager on one of our Fujitsu servers but the website refuses to be loaded:

[image: The connection was reset]

When I try to open the site over HTTP, I get redirected to the HTTPS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](http://aymanstechblog.blogspot.de/2012/05/fujitsu-serverview-raid-manager-page.html), this was caused by a [security update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2585542).

To resolve the problem,

1. Go to `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Fujitsu\ServerView Suite\RAID Manager\bin`
2. Edit `amDPatch.ini` and find the setting **AllowHTTP**.

   Change it to either **1** (allow non-SSL for all connections) or **2** (allow non-SSL for local connections).
3. Restart the ServerView RAID Manager service.

Comment: This also solved the problem with v6.6.5 when the message "the server, service, or connection is down" appeared